# Hibernate 4 finding record by property

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any specific method for finding record from database?

I don't want to use `criteria api` and `load()` only fetch data using primary key but what about if i want to find records using other columns? I know it is possible with criteria but want to know is there any other option?

Comment: You are looking for the [Querying](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-querying) and [HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html) sections of the Hibernate Core Reference Manual

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly ya that is fine, so I have only that option to write query for all properties?

Comment: Read the documentation. You can use HQL, JPQL, Criterias (through Hibernate and JPA 2 APIs) and Native SQL. When you have a more specific question make sure to come back.

Comment: I already know that and had used before but just got wonder why hibernate had not specify method like load which fetch any property from class and find record according to it, so it will be charm for users.

Comment: You have annotations and xml mapping properties to control fetching behavior if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: To write queries each and every time for different class is tedious.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35703/discussion-between-commit-and-anthony-accioly)

Comment: @commit  That is what criteria api  for do ,You have to use projections along to get required properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our discussion in chat. OP was looking for a way to query using combinations of entity fields only known at runtime. I've suggested [Criteria - Example Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-examples).

Sample from official documentation:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.setSex('F');
cat.setColor(Color.BLACK);
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Example.create(cat) )
    .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far As I know there is no method directly for that ..

You can try  using [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) or [Native SQL query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html).

And

In criteria API you need to add [Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html) to fetch the required properties on POJO's